# Array List of objects

Tags: java

I'm working on a Library system in Java.

I want to make a class `Book` and a class `Borrow` that will have `ArrayList` of Book objects and some methods like `searchBook()`.

While creating `ArrayList`, I get lots of errors.

Part of the `Book` class:

```
package  Book;
public class Book {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


}


    /********************************/

public String author;
public String title;
public int numcopies;
public Book() {};
public Book(String author, String title, int  
         numcopies)         {

            this.author = author;
            this.title = title;
            this.numcopies = numcopies;


    }
/*********************************/
```

`Borrow` class:

```
package Book;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Borrow  {

    public Book book ; 
    ArrayList<Book> BookList = new ArrayList<Book>();
    BookList.add(new Book("Author", "Title", 26));



}
```

Comment: You can't add a `Student` to a `List<Book>` unless `Student` is a subclass of `Book`, which I highly doubt is the case. You should read [ask].

Comment: sorry it's mistake i mean book not student

Comment: What errors are you getting? This is a very poor question and will be closed within a few moments. Again, read [ask].

Comment: You can't have code like that in a class body, BookList.add..., needs to be in a method.

Comment: The bottom line is that you should be learning Java from the ground up instead of fiddling around with tasks way above your understanding. There are too many wrong things in your code.

Comment: You don't just get "a lot of errors", you get *specific* errors that you should describe.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot do any computations at the class level, which means you need to do the following

```
ArrayList<Book> BookList = new ArrayList<Book>();
BookList.add(new Student("Author", "Title", 26));
```

**inside a method/function**, e.g.

```
public class Borrow  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Book> BookList = new ArrayList<Book>();
        BookList.add(new Book("Author", "Title", 26));
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't add a `Student` to an `ArrayList<Book>`. Read the OP again. It has been edited.

Comment: `functionName` does nothing meaningful and why a Book class variable in Borrow?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson the OP had a Book variable in their Borrow class, so I guess they probably want it there

Comment: For no good reason it appears but feel free to ask OP about it.

Comment: Not sure if I am blind or if I'm blind, but I don't see `functionName` anywhere.

Comment: @Gendarme it was there in a previous edit of this answer. So no, you're not blind lol

Comment: You are aware that the Borrow class is completely empty when it comes to variables now and only holds a main method?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson if you have a better answer, then provide it.

Comment: No, this is such a low quality question that needs a lot of improvement first.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is not with the ArrayList, but with your syntax.

If you want to create the ArrayList with a Student in it when constructing the Object, you should declare a constructor:

```
public Borrow() {
  bookList = new ArrayList<Book>();
  bookList.add(new Book("Author", "Title", 26));
}
```

And then make `bookList` a field of your `Borrow` class :

```
public class Borrow  {

    private ArrayList<Book> bookList;

    public Borrow() {
      bookList = new ArrayList<Book>();
      bookList.add(new Book("Author", "Title", 26));
    }
}
```

You cannot have code lying like that in middle of your class.
Also, you shouldn't have `public` fields as it breaks [encapsulation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_encapsulation.htm).

Comment: sorry student was a mistake i mean Book

Comment: There must be a better way to add a book than adding one in the constructor with hard coded values, don't you think?